# Is it necessary to submit for Review on Facebook for publish_actions permission?

Tags: facebook

I have an app that shares a google map link on Facebook in background when my application is in background.So is it necessary to submit for Review on Facebook for publish_actions permission? if it's yes then what is the procedure for submitting app for review?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's necessary to submit for Login Review, and no, I doubt that it will pass it, because auto-posting is not allowed via th Platform Policies.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review
- https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control (points 2.2 & 2.3)

Comment: but when my application in foreground, if user click on share i can show a share dialogue box, but when application in background mode i want to share its location with google map link. what should i do?

Comment: "Background sharing" i.e. auto-posting is not allowed. See the docs I linked.

Comment: if Facebook will not allow background sharing then what is the use of FBSDKShareAPI?

Comment: `Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.`

Comment: what if i share post in background using FBSDKGraphRequest?

Comment: Go read Platform Policy. Your app is not allowed to publish content “automatically”, the user has to actively trigger it each single time.